# how piwik extension for magento 2 takes data to its database?

Tags: magento, matomo, magento-2.0

the tracker collects data on the web page it's included in and sends it to Piwik by calling the HTTP tracking API. I got this information,but i am unable to find the piece of code for this. can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Which piece of code are you looking for? The JavaScript that Piwik runs to gather data about the browser of the web page it is included in?

Comment: I am looking for the code through which data from Piwik extension(product details like name,id, customer details like email,username) goes to the piwik database.

Comment: On the Piwik integrations page at http://piwik.org/integrate/ there's a Magento extension - http://github.com/henkelund/magento2-henhed-piwik - that could be the code you're looking for.

Comment: In the source code,how is piwik.php collecting the data from the extension? How is  piwik.php and the extension calling each other?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Magento, so can't answer that. But reading through the Piwik Magento extension code should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have integrated the [Henhed-Piwik](http://github.com/henkelund/magento2-henhed-piwik) extension to magento 2 and configured your piwik credentials in the following section **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Piwik API** with piwik-host URL, user id tracking, etc.

Since you have integrated the **Henhed-Piwik** to your magento 2 (Hope you have compiled your magento 2 and upgraded). This extension automatically places the java script tracking code to your magento site. Whenever you visit the site it automatically tracks your actions, clicks, impressions, referrals etc., asynchronously.

The role of ***piwik.js*** and ***piwik.php*** are as follows:

1. Your tracking site consists of a global variable   `var _paq = _paq || [];` and  `_paq.push(['trackPageView']);` this actually mentions the what are all the features in piwik you would like to track.
2. This code defines the script execution mode, i.e asynchronous and you are sending all the data to ***piwik.js*** file. `g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js';`.
3. The same ***piwik.js*** file also calls the API methods in the ***piwik.php*** file of Piwik Analytics Tool and tracks all your web site data and stores into the MySQL database, where you have configured while installing and setting up of your piwik.

Hope, I have answered your question.